# Why this block of code throws an exception in win8 rtm but not in win8 rp?

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-8, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

> Preconditions: Windows 8 Pro RTM + VS2012 Ultimate RTM

1.The following codes are in App.xaml.cs.
  If the user open this app for the first time, the app will create a xml.

```
    private async void CheckXML()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile file1 = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("BetterTask.xml");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            CreateXML();
        }
    }


    private async void CreateXML()
    {
        StorageFile file2 = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("BetterTask.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (var writeStream1 = await file2.OpenStreamForWriteAsync() as Stream)
        {
            XDocument doc1 = new XDocument(              
                                            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),  
                                            new XElement("tasks", 
                                                new XElement("task",  
                                                    new XElement("title", "Wish you enjoy this App :)"),
                                                    new XElement("due", DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")))));
            doc1.Save(writeStream1);
            await writeStream1.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
```

2.when the app starts, in the OnNavigatedTo event in the MainPage.xaml, it will read the xml to retrieve the data.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadTasks("all");
        ShowTime();
    }

    private async void ReadTasks(string action)
    {
        StorageFile file1 = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(xmlfilename);
        var ReadStream1 = await file1.OpenStreamForReadAsync() as Stream;
        XDocument doc1 = new XDocument();
        doc1 = XDocument.Load(ReadStream1);
        ReadStream1.Dispose(); 
        .......
     }
```

.3. **What Happens**: when the app first starts, the following code throws an error:

```
    var ReadStream1 = await file1.OpenStreamForReadAsync() as Stream;
```

> **Error:**
>   UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code
>   Access is denied. 
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

```
I check the folder, the xml file is created when the error happen.
```

.4. **Something more**:When I reopen the app, nothing happens, it works like a charm. I don't know why, the app works great in Win8 RP and VS 2012 RC. I change nothing but why can't it run in Win8 RTM with VC2012 RTM

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to open the file while it is still being generated in a different thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your second code block uses a variable name **xmlfilename** I don't know if in fact you are trying to open the same file, but I'm guessing that you are. Since the operation to create the file in App.xaml.cs and the operation to read the file in MainPage.xaml.cs are both asynchronous, they're probably happening at the same time. The easiest way to resolve this would be to have an application-level Task variable that represents the creation of the XML file. Like so:

```
Task creatingFile = CheckXML();
createFile.Start();
```

Now, in your MainPage.xaml file you can check to see if the task is still running by using **creatingFile.IsCompleted** (or **IsFaulted**). If the task is completed, then you can just open the file. If the task has not yet completed, you can use **creatingFile.ContinueWith(...)** to schedule the file to be opened after it is created.

Also, don't forget to wrap files in using statements to make sure they're closed when you're done using them. Like this:

```
using (var ReadStream1 = await file1.OpenStreamForReadAsync() as Stream)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jared is correct about this being done at the same time, but I'm not too fond of the application wide Task reference. The reason this is happening is because you cannot await a method that returns void. You've marked the methods `CheckXML` and `CreateXML` as async void. An async void method is a "fire and forget" method. Your code will execute it asynchronously. When you page is navigated to it tries to read it.

I would suggest creating a method to read the file, if the file exists just read, is not create first then read.

Options 1:

```
private async void ReadTasks(string action)
{
    // This is a fire and forget method

    StorageFile file = await GetXmlFile(xmlfilename);

    var ReadStream1 = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync() as Stream;
    XDocument doc1 = new XDocument();
    doc1 = XDocument.Load(ReadStream1);
    ReadStream1.Dispose(); 
    .......
}

private async Task<StorageFile> GetXmlFile(string xmlfilename)
{
    try
    {
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(xmlfilename);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        file = await CreateXml(xmlfilename);
    }
    return file;
}

private async Task<StorageFile> CreateXML(string xmlfilename)
{
    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(xmlfilename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (var writeStream1 = await file2.OpenStreamForWriteAsync() as Stream)
    {
        XDocument doc1 = new XDocument(              
                                        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),  
                                        new XElement("tasks", 
                                            new XElement("task",  
                                                new XElement("title", "Wish you enjoy this App :)"),
                                                new XElement("due", DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")))));
        doc1.Save(writeStream1);
        await writeStream1.FlushAsync();
    }
    return file;
}
```