# Xml gets corrupted each time I append a node

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, windows-phone-8.1

I have an Xml file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hashnotes>
  <hashtags>
    <hashtag>#birthday</hashtag>
    <hashtag>#meeting</hashtag>
    <hashtag>#anniversary</hashtag>
  </hashtags>
  <lastid>0</lastid>
  <Settings>
    <Font>Arial</Font>
    <HashtagColor>red</HashtagColor>
    <passwordset>0</passwordset>
    <password></password>
  </Settings>
</hashnotes>
```

I then call a function to add a node in the xml,

The function is :

```
public static void CreateNoteNodeInXDocument(XDocument argXmlDoc, string argNoteText)
    {
       string lastId=((Convert.ToInt32(argXmlDoc.Root.Element("lastid").Value)) +1).ToString();
       string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        argXmlDoc.Element("hashnotes").Add(new XElement("Note", new XAttribute("ID", lastId), new XAttribute("Date",date),new XElement("Text", argNoteText)));
        //argXmlDoc.Root.Note.Add new XElement("Text", argNoteText)
        List<string> hashtagList = Utilities.GetHashtagsFromText(argNoteText);

        XElement reqNoteElement = (from xml2 in argXmlDoc.Descendants("Note")
                            where xml2.Attribute("ID").Value == lastId
                            select xml2).FirstOrDefault();
        if (reqNoteElement != null)
        {
            foreach (string hashTag in hashtagList)
            {
                reqNoteElement.Add(new XElement("hashtag", hashTag));
            }
        }

        argXmlDoc.Root.Element("lastid").Value = lastId;
    }
```

After this I save the xml.
Next time when I try to load the Xml, it fails with an exception:
*System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it.*

Here is the code to load the XML:

```
private static XDocument hashNotesXDocument;
private static Stream hashNotesStream;

StorageFile hashNoteXml = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync("hashnotes.xml");
hashNotesStream = await hashNoteXml.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
hashNotesXDocument = XDocument.Load(hashNotesStream);
```

and I save it using:

```
hashNotesXDocument.Save(hashNotesStream);
```

Comment: here is a link you can checkout https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e3f3c6b1-43ee-46d7-bc09-edb8dcedb8d1/add-node-existing-xml-file?forum=csharpgeneral looks like you're not adding `XmlNode` but `XElement` instead

Comment: Thanks for the response but the link that you provided has code to add a node using XML DOM, but I want to use LINQ to XML to do the same.

Comment: What does the XML file look like if you open it after saving it?

Comment: I cannot open it as I am developing windows phone 8.1 app and I am saving it in the installation folder for my app and this folder is not accessible using explorer.

Comment: Load the file into a string first and look at the string to see what's wrong.  Then do `XDocument.Parse()` on the string.

Comment: @ng-R then create a windows project copy your related code to it , save the file wherever you want and open it with notepad. This would be much faster than waiting for answers

Comment: How do you save your document after you modify it?

Comment: @ng-R - could you edit your question to show your methods to save and load the `XDocument`?  I made a guess in my answer about what you might be doing, but it would be easier for us to help you if you showed us the code.  I tested your method `CreateNoteNodeInXDocument` and it seems fine.

Comment: Could it be that you are appending the new XML to the old XML file rather than overwriting the old XML file with the new contents?  That could also produce this exception.

Comment: @dbc I have edited the question and included the code for loading and saving the xml

Comment: do you reset (set the position to 0) the stream. Because as I understand your code, you are adding a modified copy a the xml at the end of the original xml. BTW: using `OpenStreamForWriteAsync` for reading sounds weird. You should use (using) a stream for read, and another for write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show all of your code, but it looks like you open the XML file, read the XML from it into an `XDocument`, edit the `XDocument` in memory, then write back to the opened stream.  Since the stream is still open it will be positioned at the end of the file and thus the new XML will be appended to the file.

Suggest eliminating `hashNotesXDocument` and `hashNotesStream` as static variables, and instead open and read the file, modify the `XDocument`, then open and write the file using the pattern shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582147%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I'm working only on desktop code (using an older version of .Net) so I can't test this, but something like the following should work:

```
    static async Task LoadUpdateAndSaveXml(Action<XDocument> editor)
    {
        XDocument doc;
        var xmlFile = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync("hashnotes.xml");
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(await xmlFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync()))
        {
            doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
        }        

        if (doc != null)
        {
            editor(doc);
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(await xmlFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()))
            {
                // Truncate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454584/writing-a-shorter-stream-to-a-storagefile
                if (writer.CanSeek && writer.Length > 0) 
                    writer.SetLength(0);
                doc.Save(writer);
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, be sure to [create the file before using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410006/why-this-block-of-code-throws-an-exception-in-win8-rtm-but-not-in-win8-rp).